# Why does not work inserting HTML in Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

I have HTML code:

```
<div dynamic="html"></div>
```

And Angular JS in AJAX response:

```
$scope.html = content;
```

My dirrective `dynamic` looks as:

```
.directive('dynamic', function ($compile) {
            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                replace: true,
                link: function (scope, ele, attrs) {
                    scope.$watch(attrs.dynamic, function(html) {
                        ele.html(html);
                        $compile(ele.contents())(scope);
                    });
                }
            };
        })
```

So, when I have `$scope.html` with HTML code in response then `dynamic` does not insert(prepend) this code in div block. Why?

Comment: Did you try the `template`? See the example under [Template-extending directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

Answer (score 1):

> ...And Angular JS in AJAX response:

I cannot see any ajax call being made to get the template.

> So, when I have $scope.html with HTML code in response then dynamic
>   does not insert(prepend) this code in div block. Why?

You are not seeing any content because `html`, the callback response in $watch is `undefined`

From my understanding, I presume you want to have a directive attribute with value supplied as an html file where you could make an ajax request to.

```
<div dynamic="file.html"></div>
```

Further, in the `link:{ ... }` function of your attribute, you can make an ajax call to supplied template path, get its html as response data and insert/append that into the div block containing your directive.

```
 link: function (scope, ele, attrs) {
   $http.get('file.html').then(function(content){
     ele.html(content.data);
     $compile(ele.contents())(scope);
   })
 }
```

Here's the [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/312EZQlNPnbdSVESEAng?p=preview)

Comment: Seems it that i need but instead file I have returned HTML block, that need insert to page

Answer (score 0):

Your code Working fine with proper binding of angular variable. See here the [**Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/5cD5pVvLU91PVtIV7kBa?p=preview) which give you the Idea what you are missing in your code.

**Update**

As you want to replace directive element with your content you need to use `ele.replaceWith` that will replace the directive element.

**Code**

```
link: function(scope, ele, attrs) {
  var watcher = scope.$watch(attrs.dynamic, function(newhtml, oldhtml) {
    if(newhtml){
      ele.replaceWith($compile(newhtml)(scope));
      watcher(); //destructing watcher
    }
  });
}
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/rXBaMLoNDEBknDip6k1H?p=preview) Here

Comment: Tried you solution, does not work foe me, not prepend HTML in block div. I get error also: `$sce.trustedAsHtml`

Comment: @Caur it appends see here but binding won't work http://plnkr.co/edit/rXBaMLoNDEBknDip6k1H?p=preview

Comment: No, i need re-compile HTM because there are directory in HTML

Comment: @Caur do you want it to prepent to your directive div?

Comment: Yes, I want that HTM will be insert to div and was compile

Comment: @Caur give me a minute please

Comment: @Caur check updated plunkr..I assume that you want to render the html only once..Is it correct or do i change that?

Comment: No, for what did you give me pop-up window. I have Ajax method in angular js that gets one HTML with angular js directives inside as: `<timer>`. I need compile this code and insert `.prepend()` to block html in page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80490/discussion-between-pankajparkar-and-caur).

Comment: @Caur that was my bad..I attached wrong plunkr url..see the updated..It working now with proper binding

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use `ngTransclude` to do this.

That allows you to do something like:

```
<div yourdirective>
   <h1> Some custom HTML</h1>
</div>
```

Then if you're directive must include `<ngTransclude></ngTransclude>` which will then include the HTML that you put inside, into the directive.

Documentation here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude

Comment: How I can insert HTML from Ajax to this directive?

Comment: Sure - you can just use an `{{expression}}` in there AFAIK